# Creating an employee schedule

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help in how to think about creating a work schedule. Each employee needs x amount of shifts, x amount of weekends, and can't work back to back. There are other rules I would build in, like employee requests, holidays etc

I am thinking of approaching it such that I would create every possible schedule and weigh them based on a set of rules.

However, with 14 shifts and 34 employees, the number of possible schedules for a give 2 month block would be astronomical.

Should I use a specific library for this?
is this something Javascript can handle?

Other Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request is waaaay too big, fill in a few variables (ie. amount of shifts/amount of weekends) otherwise you're going to waste so much time going through possibilities (1,391,975,640) that it would be futile. Additionally, you could save time by adding a maximum and minimum shift time, and a maximum and minimum weekend time. Once you fill in those variables, you can use Google Sheets or Excel to create a quick employee schedule. Additionally, adding a quick formula to account for requested time off can be added to a new field.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I suppose the purpose of the original question was to create 1,000,000,000 schedules and only display the best ones. Effectively discarding the ones that don't meet the rules.  Google sheets is a good idea, but when you're filling a schedule 24,7 with 30+ rules, it's not exactly "quick"